# C++, get data member value [inappropriate design]

Tags: c++, function, templates

There is the class A

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
   private: T a1, a2;

   public:  
        A() : a1(0.0), a2(0.0) {}
        A(T a1_, T a2_) : a1(a1_), a2(a2_) {}

        void run() 
        {
         process2(a1, a2); // pass both data members
         process1(a1); //pass only a1
        }
};

template <typename T>
void process2(T a1, T a2)
{
    //both a1, a2 are available
}

template <typename T>
void process1(T a1)
{
    //only a1 is available
    //How to get a2 ?
}
```

Due to the inappropriate data model, some "hack" is necessary :-).

```
int main()
{
   A<double > a;
   a.run();
}
```

The class member run() calls the function process1() with the parameter a1. Is there any reasonable way, how to get a2 value inside process1() function, after its calling (for example friend function, global variable, etc...)? Keep in mind that the function signature

```
void process1(T a1)
```

needs to be preserved...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Only through horrible global variables.

Comment: There's always a rewrite.

Comment: Sounds like a XY-problem actually.

Comment: `void process1 (T a1, T a2 = whatEverValueOfa2TheOldCallersUsed)` might be what you need, but it is kind of unclear what you try to do here. (Agree, sounds like XY-Problem)

Comment: @Blindy. Yes, of course. But it is a part of the library, written by the third person...

Comment: Which part is the third-party library and which part do you have control over?

Comment: The library returns data into A class, they represent a triangulation model. There is the class B containing optimizing function with the templatized weight function, where the current weight is computed over the model in A. However, the general weight function has only one argument, a matrix of input parameters, which is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this in C++, but I know you can do it in C++11.

Try to create a lambda based on `process2` that contains an `a2`.

Then that lambda has a signature that takes one `A`, but runs `process2` with two `A`s: one is what you pass to it, the other is what's carried by the lambda.